# How do I get a section of a Dataframe that meets a certain criteria?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get a section of a dataframe that meets a certain requirement.

I want to do:

```
new_df = old_df[old_df.timevariable.date() == thisdateiwant]
```

Is there an efficient way to do this that works? 
the issue here is the .date() part. I've done this before using the same syntax but not with a modifier on the part of old_df. For example of old_df.timevariable is a datetime, then I could match this with a `==datetime` but as I want a date, I need to modify each element in the dataframe, which the syntax doesn't like.

I know I could take it all out and have it loop through with a bunch of variables, but I'm pretty sure this would be much slower. The first code snippet seemed to be the fastest way of doing this (like a WHERE SQL clause), although doesn't seem to work if you need to modify the variable you're comparing (such as .date()).

The old_df is about (900k, 15) in size so I want to get something efficient. Currently, I'm just changing variables and reimporting from SQL which seems to take 5-10 seconds for each date (`thisdateiwant`). I presume something in python with the larger initial database will be quicker than this. Typically it returns about 30k rows into new_df for each date.

What is the fastest way of doing this?

**Edit**

Happy to mark this as a duplicate, I got it working from some code in that other question (from @Pault).
basically did:

```
mask = old_db['timevariable'] >= thisdateiwant
mask2 =  old_db['timevariable'] < thisdateiwant (+1day)
new_db = old_db.loc[mask]
new_db = new_db.loc[mask2]
```

I don't think there's an easy way to do both masks at the same time, seemed to throw and error. It's nice and quick so I'm happy.

Comment: You can chain together multiple boolean expressions like this: `new_df = old_df[(old_df.variable == setvariable) & (old_df.timevariable.date() == thisdateiwant)]`. You'll have to use the bitwise comparison operators (ie `&` instead of `and`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas)

Comment: Best thing is to use pandas [query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html#pandas-dataframe-query) function.

Comment: Your question seems to be asking two different ones: 1) how to filter by date or 2) how to filter across a *bunch of variables*? You could use SQL to query. Please post sample data, more code (not line snippets), and desired results.

Comment: Happy to mark this as a duplicate, I got it working from some code in that other question (from Pault).
basically did:
'
    mask = old_db['timevariable'] >= thisdateiwant
    mask2 =  old_db['timevariable'] < thisdateiwant (+1day)
    new_db = old_db.loc[mask]
    new_db = new_db.loc[mask2]'

Answer (score 0):

if your column is truly a timestamp then you can make use of the `dt` accessor.

```
new_df = old_df[old_df.timevariable.dt.floor('D') == '2018-05-09']
```

otherwise change the target column to timestamp using `pd.to_datetime`

```
old_df[timevariable] = pd.to_datetime(old_df[timevariable])
```

ranges of dates are supported more naturally without the dt accessor

```
new_df = old_df[old_df.timevariable >= '2018-05-09'] <- dates after may 9th inclusive
```